# Firebase firestore information not rendering whilst using getStaticProps on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from firebase firestore using Next.js's getStaticProps. Without using getStaticProps, the data renders normally but when I use it I get the error

> res.json() is not a function

This is how my code looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { db } from '@/firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

     
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await getDocs(collection(db, 'blogs'));
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
        props: {
            blogs: data
        }
    }
}

function index({blogs}) {
  return (
    <div>
        {blogs.map(blog => {
            <p>{blog.title}</p>
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default index
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are under the impression that `getDocs` returns some sort of express-like Response object, which is not at all the case.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation and examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) that show how to use `getDocs()`.  It yields a DocumentSnapshot object, and that object doesn't have a `json` method.

Your code should look more like the documented example:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

You will need to write appropriate code to turn all of the DocumentSnapshot objects into whatever it is you want the user to see.

Comment: I know thats how it is but when I write it like that it still refuses. I have updated the code to the previous way I'd return it check again. I get the error, 'TypeError: querySnapshot is not a function'

Comment: You now have a completely new question with a new code and symptoms.  It really should be posted as a new question entirely since your first problem no longer exists.  I've manually rolled back the question to its first version so that the answer here now matches the original question, which will make it more helpful for others who might have made the same mistake.